# Installation of LPRng (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: installation, printing

I have problems with LPRng installation (I am Linux beginner).

http://lprng.com/LPRng-Reference/LPRng-Reference.html#INSTALLATION - installation guide
http://lprng.com/PrintingCookbook/index.html#AEN1563

Could you write me here please, step by step, what I have to do (write into terminal) for succesful installation?
I'm trying to do the first step of guide `(h4: {4} % gunzip -c LPRng-<version>.tgz | tar xvf -)` but unsuccessfuly. (I put the source file to `usr/bin`, `usr/sbin` and `usr/etc`).

I'm desperate, help me please :)

Thank you and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

LPRng is in [Ubuntu Repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&searchon=names&keywords=lprng)

You can install it with;

```
sudo apt-get install lprng lprng-doc
```